# HTML <form> elements using table

Tags: html

I am trying to create a group of elements in html **(Yes, in HTML ONLY!!! I'm trying not  to apply CSS yet, for this!!!)** form using table, under the  named 2. Pizza Order Details, as you can see here: [image: Screenshot01]

Right now I'm stuck on the **Type of pizza** element. I want to make the colon (**:**) for **Type of Pizza** to be placed in line in between (but after!) the words **"Type of"** and **"Pizza"**, like in Screenshot01 but instead I'm getting this: [image: Screenshot02]

My colon (**:**) for **Type of Pizza** comes directly right after the word **Pizza** instead. **I don't want this**. I need it to be placed like in Screenshot01.

Here is the code I made:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>2. Pizza Order Details:</legend>
<table style="width:860px">
<tr>
<td align="right">Type of&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>Pizza :</td>
<td>
<select>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Hawaiian Chicken">Hawaiian Chicken</option>
<option value="Cheese Deluxe">Cheese Deluxe</option>
<option value="Chicken Pepperoni">Chicken Pepperoni</option>
<option value="BBQ Chicken">BBQ Chicken</option>
<option value="Super Supreme">Super Supreme</option>
</select>
</td>
<td style="width:1px" align="left"><strong>|</strong></td>
<td style="width:70px" align="right">Quantity :</td>
<td><input size="3" placeholder="0" type="text"></td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Size :</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="size">Small
<input type="radio" name="size">Medium
<input type="radio" name="size">Big
</td>   
<td style="width:1px" align="left"><strong>|</strong></td>
<td style="width:70px" align="right">Topping :</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Cheese">Cheese
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Sausages">Sausages
<input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Olives">Olives
</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Date :</td>
<td><input size="12" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text"></td> 
<td style="width:1px" align="left"><strong>|</strong></td>
<td style="width:70px" align="right">Time :</td>
<td><input size="7" placeholder="hh/mm" type="text"></td>   
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Kindly point out what my errors, or what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: This problem can be easily solved but, IMHO, "Type of pizza" is redundant as you already are setting the **Pizza** order details. So, using "Type" as label not just solve your problem but also is more better looking and pragmatic.

Comment: Try putting the colons in it's own cell/column and play with the styling.

Comment: Can't be done without creating a `td` for your `:`.

Comment: NO prob.. glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong, because you are using `<br>` ,which will break the line and the `:` will come accordingly.

You can use `<td align="right">Type of Pizza :</td>` .
This will show the label on one line, which is really good approach.